# Close parent process if child closed or crashed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I have a Win32 program. This program creates a process with CreateProcess function to run another program. I want to parent process to be closed, if the child process was closed or crashed for any reason.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) function on the created process' handle, like so:

```
STARTUPINFO si {sizeof(si)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi {};

CreateProcessW(/*your arguments here*/);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Note that if you do use `INFINITE` as the wait time, the function blocks until the process terminates. If you want the parent process to be doing other things in the mean time, it's best to have that code in a separate thread.

If you want the parent process to be a complete wrapper for the created process, use [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) when you're done to obtain the child process' exit code.

```
DWORD dwExit;
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExit);
```

This code was just a simple example. All three functions I mentioned in my answer can fail, and robust code would check their return values and act accordingly in the case of failure.

Comment: *"If you want the parent process to be doing other things in the mean time, it's best to have that code in a separate thread."* - This is *one* way to do it, but not necessarily the best. `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` may be more appropriate. For one, it doesn't require you to synchronize with yet another thread.